# find rows with outlier values in any columns

Tags: r, dataframe, outliers

Given data like below in a dataframe df, need to extract rows which has outliers for any of the columns.

```
text = "
A,B,C,D,E,F,G
93,53,221,314,104,721,179
100,58,218,318,93,718,181
601,61,228,829,106,739,190
510,60,229,739,95,707,181
779,51,242,1021,105,756,180
848,57,228,1076,93,710,191
94,52,227,321,95,723,179
712,58,242,954,486,750,180
,53,,10289,298,841,210
696,53,233,929,95,751,180
101,57,220,321,415,796,179
100,60,226,326,104,744,180
181,58,234,415,105,2870,468
,57,,10277,,,918
"
df = read.table(textConnection(text), sep=",", header = T)
```

Outlier is defined as in boxplots - Q1-1.5IQR / Q3+1.5IQR. So rows with any column (one or more) having outlier value for the column will be in our output set.

Also want to get a second set of rows where instead of outliers as per classical definition above, rows with any column values only above the Q3+1.5IQR value will be in our output set.

I'm facing some challenge get this done. The pseudo code for I'm thinking is as follows

1. Compute the boxplot stats for each column
2. Using Q1 and Q3 values get the row indices where column value is > Q3 and < Q1

With respect to #1, I have tried the following

```
> sapply(df, boxplot.stats)
      A         B         C         D         E         F         G        
stats Numeric,5 Numeric,5 Numeric,5 Numeric,5 Numeric,5 Numeric,5 Numeric,5
n     12        14        12        14        13        13        14       
conf  Numeric,2 Numeric,2 Numeric,2 Numeric,2 Numeric,2 Numeric,2 Numeric,2
out   Integer,0 Integer,0 Integer,0 Integer,2 Integer,3 Integer,2 Integer,3
```

But this doesn't see to give the output like `stats 
a vector of length 5, containing the extreme of the lower whisker, the lower ‘hinge’, the median, the upper ‘hinge’ and the extreme of the upper whisker.` which could have used in #2.

Comment: It's very difficult to use the data as you've provided it here, no tools (that I'm aware of) read this natively (and return an R-friendly object). Would you consider doing two things? (1) Use `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)` (or similarly programmatically) for providing sample data; and (2) can the same effect be had with (say) 10 rows of data? (3) What does `A` (time) have to do with any of this? It also helps to not give us things that have nothing to do with your question. And lastly, as RAB suggested, (4) please show what code you've tried so far, it will help guide coding style, etc.

Comment: @r2evans - updated the question.

Comment: If you look at the output of one call, `boxplot.stats` is returning a `list`, and the value returned is actually advertised as *"List with named components as follows"*. You might do something like `sapply(df, function(x) boxplot.stats(x)$stats)` to get something more useful.

Comment: `> sapply(df, function(x) boxplot.stats(x)$stats)
         A  B     C    D   E   F     G
[1,]  93.0 51 218.0  314  93 707 179.0
[2,] 100.0 53 223.5  321  95 721 180.0
[3,] 345.5 57 228.0  784 104 744 180.5
[4,] 704.0 58 233.5 1021 106 756 191.0
[5,] 848.0 61 242.0 1076 106 796 191.0`  - how do we access the `upper whisker` from this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can write a function to find out if the value is an outlier or not

```
IsOutlier <- function(data) {
   lowerq = quantile(data, na.rm = TRUE)[2]
   upperq = quantile(data, na.rm = TRUE)[4]
   iqr = upperq - lowerq 
   threshold_upper = (iqr * 1.5) + upperq
   threshold_lower = lowerq - (iqr * 1.5)
   data > threshold_upper | data <  threshold_lower 
}
```

and select rows with at least one outlier

```
df[rowSums(sapply(df, IsOutlier), na.rm = TRUE) > 0, ]

#     A  B   C     D   E    F   G
#8  712 58 242   954 486  750 180
#9   NA 53  NA 10289 298  841 210
#11 101 57 220   321 415  796 179
#13 181 58 234   415 105 2870 468
#14  NA 57  NA 10277  NA   NA 918
```

---

Similarly, for second set we can use this function

```
IsOutlier_upper <- function(data) {
   upperq = quantile(data, na.rm = TRUE)[4]
   lowerq = quantile(data, na.rm = TRUE)[2]
   iqr = upperq - lowerq 
   data > (upperq + 1.5 * iqr) 
}
```